# SELECTing a ROWTIME field in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Bit of a strange issue, not sure I will be able to explain it properly, but I will try.
I have created a Table with SQL CREATE TABLE and I set up a watermark column called `_ingested_timestamp`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE
  (
      id                    INT NOT NULL,
      ...
      ...
      _ingested_timestamp   TIMESTAMP(3),
      WATERMARK FOR _ingested_timestamp AS _ingested_timestamp - INTERVAL '10' SECOND,
  PRIMARY KEY(id) NOT ENFORCED
)
WITH(...);
```

I then have a `SELECT` using data from the above table, something like this:

```
SELECT
 item.id,
 ...
 ...
 item._ingested_timestamp as event_time, 
FROM MY_TABLE as item JOIN ....;
```

However, this fails with an exception around `Conversion to relational algebra failed to preserve datatypes`.

Specifically, there seems to be a mismatch with due to the fact that `event_time` is expected to be `ROWTIME` but it is not (or the other way around):

```
validated type:
RecordType(INTEGER NOT NULL id, ..., TIMESTAMP(3) *ROWTIME* event_time) NOT NULL
converted type:
RecordType(INTEGER NOT NULL id, ..., TIMESTAMP(3) event_time) NOT NULL
```

As you can see, the only difference in the exception message seems to be about the type of `event_time`.

Can anyone help me out here?

What exactly is the issue here, and how can I use a rowtime field in a SQL without facing this issue?
Thanks

Comment: I also tried to remove the `WATERMARK` from the `CREATE TABLE` (effectively making `_ingested_timestamp` just a normal column, and indeed that removed the error, confirming that the issue ins indeed around the column being marked as `ROWTIME`.

Comment: I suspect the JOIN used in the SELECT is causing the problem. What kind of JOIN is this?